# BizTalk weird mapping problem

Tags: biztalk

I'm mapping a HL7 schema to a home made schema. Now my schema looks like this:

```
<xs:element name="Patienten">
 <xs:complexType>
 <xs:sequence>
 <xs:element name="Patient">
 <xs:complexType>
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ContactNummer" nillable="true" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Voornaam" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Naam" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Plaats" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Straat" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Campus" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Kamer" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Bed" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Ontslagen" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CampusCode" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TelefoonCode" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

When I map elements from my HL7 schema and when I use a test file I get an error: "The element Patienten in namespace blabla is incomplete. List of possible elements: Patient".

I noticed that my testfile does not fill in the "straat" and "plaats" element. If i remove the mapping links of these two elements the map works fine. But I obviously need them. If I set the Patient element propertie minOccurs="0" then the validation is successfull, but I get an empty xml:

```
  <ns0:Patienten xmlns:ns0="http://nextel.zna.be/ZNA_Nextel_Patient.xsd" />
```

If I remove the "Patient" element and just use the other elements as subelements of "Patienten" then the map works fine! But I need the subroot "Patient". I have been toying arround with min and max Occurs because I notice that these make a difference, but I'm still not getting to my solution. If I use a test example it works fine, so I don't get why it's not working...

Anyone has any ideas or similar problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema that you have defined requires the Patient element to exist, just as you noted when modifying the minOccurs attribute. Could it be that the testfile and map you are using does not fill any of the subelements at all, therefor not creating the Patient element?

A way to check this could be to use a static value for one of the target elements, this way you would ensure that the target document is not empty.